# QT VS Tools how to use qt static class library correctly

Tags: qt, shared-libraries

I am trying to work on qt class libraries and I want to include a qt class library in a qt application.

Platform is visual studio 2022, Qt tools and Qt 6.4.1.

Application and class library I created via project wizard.
I have included the class library via "Verweise" and added the path to the header and library path in the QT project settings.

VS Project:
[image]

QT project settings
[image]

Testlib.h

```
#pragma once
#include "testlib_global.h"

class TESTLIB_EXPORT TestLib
{
    public:
    TestLib();
    void SayHello();
};
```

Testlib_global.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

#ifndef BUILD_STATIC
# if defined(TESTLIB_LIB)
#  define TESTLIB_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
# else
#  define TESTLIB_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
# endif
#else
# define TESTLIB_EXPORT
#endif
```

Testlib.cpp

```
#include "TestLib.h"

TestLib::TestLib()
{
}

void TestLib::SayHello()
{
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>
#include "testlib.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    TestLib* lib = new TestLib();
    lib->SayHello();

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

After compiling I get the following errors

[image]

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK2019 Reference to unresolved external symbol ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl TestLib::TestLib(void)" (__imp_??0TestLib@@QEAA@XZ)" in function "main".  TestApp C:\Users\arne\workspace4\TestApp\main.obj 1

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression state
Error LNK2019 Reference to unresolved external symbol ""__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl TestLib::sayHello(void)" (__imp_?sayHello@TestLib@@QEAAXXZ)" in function "main". TestApp C:\Users\arne\workspace4\TestApp\main.obj 1

Two unresolved external
```

Probably this is a beginner's problem - I'm just switching from c# to c++ due to the project and it's much more complex.

Since the application itself is already very complex i wanted to at least create the structures correctly right at the beginning and for that i need several libraries

Thanks for any support

Testlib project settings

[image]

Comment: Do you compile the `Testlib.cpp` file too? You should link against the `TestLib` library too.

Comment: You should also define `TESTLIB_LIB` in your `TestLib` project to export the `TestLib` symbols.

Comment: Hello vahaccho - thanks for quick response. Do I have to add #define TESTLIB_LIB in testlib.cpp? Maybe you could show this in my code example?

Comment: No, you need to add TESTLIB_LIB define in your VS project's settings (TestLib settings) - "C/C++/Preprocessor" tab.

Comment: I post a screenshot - TESTLIB_LIB is set in preprocessor settings. I also try it with #pragma comment(lib, "TestLib.lib") command in testlib.h and add the path to the library folder to linker additional library directories in TestApp project. Nothing helps

Comment: Your setting is wrong. Please look at the `Testlib_global.h` file. It states: `#ifndef BUILD_STATIC and # if defined(TESTLIB_LIB)`. I.e. you need to define only `TESTLIB_LIB`.

Answer (score 0):

> Error LNK2019 Reference to unresolved external symbol ""__declspec(dllimport)

if i get this error, try edit main.cpp, from

> #include "testlib.h"

to

```
#define BUILD_STATIC
#include "testlib.h"
```